# In datetime, (change) doesn't work and (ngModelChange) called at page load too

Tags: angular

I use [this plugin](https://nkalinov.github.io/ng2-datetime/) for Angular 2. I want to call a function when the date changes on input. If I use `(change)`, it doesn't trigger the function, but if I use `(ngModelChange)` it triggers the function but also it is triggered on page load.

So, I either need to make `(change)` works or make the `(ngModelChange)` not to fire at page load. Any idea?

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <label for="datetimepicker2i" class="col-form-label text-md-right">date</label>
     <datetime [timepicker]="false" [datepicker]="datepickerOpts" [(ngModel)]="mymodel.date" (ngModelChange)="callAFunction()" name="datetimepicker2i" id="datetimepicker2i"></datetime>
</div>
```

Comment: "I use this plugin for Angular 2." What plugin ? the issue seems to come from it, no one can help you with that, except the author.

Comment: **facepalm** I thought I linked the page of plugin. However, I am not sure if it is related with the plugin or with Angular directly. That's why I asked here first.